# VirtualBox with inaccessible snapshot

Tags: virtualbox

So I have a VM done with VirtualBox a few year back, then, 2 years ago, I created a new one using the existing HDD, so VirtualBox decided it will create a differencing HDD instead of a new one like I wanted. So I ended up with 2 VM, one good, and one based on the first one but not independent of it. Time came when my second VM became inaccessible, and now, I cannot access it (obviously, from the title)

What can I do? I have an invoicing app that runs in this second inaccessible VM that I can not recover and I need it badly.

So how can I make it accessible again (the snapshot)?

The error that I receive when trying to access the inaccessible VM is:

```
Could not find an open hard disk with UUID {f749e560-88f0-46c1-8ef5-4f3445f91501}.
Result Code: 
VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
Component: 
VirtualBox
Interface: 
IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
```

I have the file {f749e560-88f0-46c1-8ef5-4f3445f91501}.vdi on my HDD. I tried to edit the VirtualBox.xml file in Documents and Settings....VirtualBox\ but without success. What I tried was replacing the UUID found there, with the one that VB says it can not find. So I pasted this {f749e560-88f0-46c1-8ef5-4f3445f91501} in there instead of the other string representing my snapshot (I did that following some forum where they described the same issue). Anyway, after editing the xml file, when I try accessing it again, the following error occurs:

```
Machine UUID {5f8dca9e-318f-4ba0-85ef-50410707b065} in 'C:\Documents and Settings\Calin\VirtualBox VMs\facturarea last\facturarea last.vbox' doesn't match its UUID {f749e560-88f0-46c1-8ef5-4f3445f91501} in the registry file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Calin/.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml'.
Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
Machine
Interface: 
IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

So I went to that XML (facturarea last.vbox) and changed there the UUID, but still the same error as the first started showing.

**Now I replaced all edited files with the original ones, and I am waiting for a little help from someone else that knows what it is to be done. My VirtualBox version is 4.3.20**

Maybe I am doing something wrong? Maybe I should try something else?

I saw an answer here saying that he ejected the ISO from the manager, but I do not understand what he means. The iso of the original (master) VM? Because no such possibility 
exists for the inaccessible VM...

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I solved my problem, and since there was no answer here to help solve it, I believe it could help others who might encounter the same situation.
So the solution is below:

1. search for the your_vm_name.vbox file on your drive (it should be located in Document and settings/username/VirtualBox VMs/
2. open the .vbox file by using other editor than notepad (use notepad++).
3. copy the hard disk uuid from the error message window, and search it in the editor.
4. you will find something similar to:

> `<StorageController name="IDE" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
>        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" port="0" device="0">
>           <Image uuid="{f749e560-88f0-46c1-8ef5-4f3445f91501}"/>
>        </AttachedDevice>
>        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" port="1" device="0"/>
>   </StorageController>`

5. remove that whole text in the StorageController TAG, along with the tags.
6. open virtual box, select that VM and right click on it, choose settings->storage

   - delete all the medium of IDE Controller.
   - add a SATA or IDE Controller (try them both if you don't remember what you used on your VM) and **add a hard disk to it by selecting the .vdi file in you VM directory**.
7. In VirtualBox, your previously 'inaccessible' Virtual machine, is now accessible again
8. Boot VM, and it will work just like nothing ever happened. If it does not work (blue screen for Windows XP) then just delete the storage you added (SATA) and add an IDE one, or the other way around.

That's all